# Should the function be 'asking questions' or 'ask questions'?

Tags: verbs, gerunds, verb-forms, conversation, functions

for example:

> A: How old are you?
>
> B: I'm 20 years old
>
> What's the function of the previous mini-dialogue?

Should the answer be:

Function: ask**ing** and answer**ing** questions

or

Function: ask and answer questions

Comment: Maybe this is a general concept I'm just missing but what does it mean by "What is the function?" Could you give us some source information so that we can understand? As knowledgeable of the situation, it seems the function or "purpose" is to find out how old someone is.

Comment: The function or *purpose* as Catija proposed of these dialogues might be: a. asking and answering questions or b. **to** ask and **to** answer questions. Although, I would prefer: purpose - obtaining information/to obtain information.

Comment: @Lucky I think your comment is exactly what the OP needs and as such should be made into an answer.

Comment: @Catija You can change the answer if you want, but I'm asking about putting "ing" at the end of the word .. I mean what would you write in the space (Function: __>here<___) would you write "finding out how old someone is" or "find out how old someone is"

Comment: Oh, you need to use the -ing form.

Comment: Either the -ing or to infinitive; you can't use bare infinitive (without to) like in your example. (This might be a case of licensing, which is somewhat complicated and I hoped someone more competent would pick this one up, but since this didn't happen I'll come up with some references for an answer :-) @AndréNeves )

Comment: You could label such mini-dialogues simply as questions and answers or use How to ask questions and give answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you intended to put these in a sentence, with the word **[function](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/function_1)**:

> the job that something is designed to do
>
> *The function of advertising is **to create** a unique image for your company.*

In your example:

> The function of this mini dialogue is **to ask and answer** questions.

[This Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=function+is+*&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cfunction%20is%20*%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bfunction%20is%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfunction%20is%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfunction%20is%20not%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfunction%20is%20a%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfunction%20is%20that%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfunction%20is%20performed%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfunction%20is%20given%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfunction%20is%20called%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfunction%20is%20used%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfunction%20is%20of%3B%2Cc0) shows that the most common word after "function is" is "to" - which indicates that infinitive should follow this construction.

("The function of this mini dialogue is asking and answering questions" - I'm not sure if this on is any good -someone who knows more about licensing should say; to-infinitive sounds better to me).

---

If you use the word **[purpose](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/purpose):**

> - purpose of:
>
> *The purpose of this dictionary is **to help** students of English.*
>
> - the purpose of doing something:
>
> *The President’s trip will have **the purpose of negotiating** a peace deal.*
>
> - for the purpose of doing something:
>
> *He went there **for the purpose of making** business contacts.*

In your example:

> The purpose of this mini dialogue is **to ask and answer** questions.
>
> This mini dialogue has/serves the purpose **of asking and answering questions**.
>
> We engaged in this mini dialogue **for the purpose of asking and answering questions**.

If you just want to use this format (that looks like a form) - both:

> **Function:** asking and answering questions

and

> **Function:** to ask and answer questions

are just fine.